# to print maximum and minimum sum of 4 out of 5 integers inputted using random

Tags: python, random, sum, max, min

In hackerrank,this question is failing 8 out of 15 testcases,can someone please correct this and tell me what is wrong.

Also I want to use random in this question and not by other methods.

```
import random
```

inputting values in list

```
arr=[int(x) for x in input().split()]
```

assigning a randomly selected large number for minimum (mini)

```
mini=1000000000000

maxi=0

for x in range(len(arr)-1):
    randomsum=sum(random.sample(arr,4))
    if randomsum<mini:
       mini=randomsum
    if randomsum >maxi:
       maxi=randomsum

print(mini,maxi)
```

Comment: Have you tried simply using more iterations (e.g. 100)? Since you only iterate len(arr)-1 times the probability that the the actual highest or lowest sum is quite low.

And especially for longer arrays, a deterministic approach might be best.

Comment: Please explain "I want to use random".  How do you intend `random` to proactively participate in a solution?

Comment: @ClF3 yes it worked ,thank you !!I am aware random function is not the best way to solve this problem but I wanted to learn how to use random function so thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Given five positive integers, find the minimum and maximum values that can be calculated by summing exactly four of the five integers. Then print the respective minimum and maximum values as a single line of two space-separated long integers.

the problem clearly states that the printed values should be the 4 SMALLEST and the 4 LARGEST integers in the list. For greater sizes of the array, random.sample could still not cover all the parts of the array. The problem requires a concrete solution and not randomizing the sample list. 2 line solution:

```
def miniMaxSum(arr):
    arr = sorted(arr)
    print(sum(arr[0:4]), sum(arr[-4:]))
```

The reason why randomly getting a sample of size 4 is because the problem requires you to explicitly get the 4 smallest and 4 biggest numbers and print their sum on the screen, therefore if you randomize the sample it is unlikely that you will get the 4 smallest and 4 biggest numbers, even if you didn't randomize but traversed the list and compares every 4 lenght subList to the samllest and biggest integer, you wouldn't succeed still, because it is still unlikely that the list is already sorted and you would get the 4 smallest and 4 biggest numbers in order. That is why something like that will fail:

```
minSeq = max(arr) + 1
maxSeq = 0
for i in range(len(arr) - 4):
    sample = sum(arr[i:i+4])
    if sample < minSeq:
        minSeq = sample
    elif sample > maxSeq:
        maxSeq = sample     
print(minSeq, maxSeq)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm is faulty.  Given your implied test of 5 integers, you take 5 random samples.  There is no guarantee whatsoever that you will happen to pick each of the minimum and maximum elements to exclude for two of those samples.

Your code finds the minimum and maximum of the samples you picked, but that's not the problem specification.  You haven't explained how you thought this was going to give you a reliable answer, so we can't "repair" your code.

This is a problem with a straightforward, deterministic solution.  Your personal requirement to involve a random component doesn't seem to fit with the goal of solving the given problem.  I recommend that you quit trying to use `random`, and simply solve the problem as given.